# Julia: Reading JLD file - filename.jld does not seem to be a Julia data or HDF5 file

Tags: file, makefile, julia

l have successfully stored my matrix of size(10000,5000) in a jld file . the file is created and the matrix is stored in this file :

```
file = jldopen("/path to my file/data.jld", "w")
write(file, "a", a)
```

but when l try to read the file using these instruction l get back this error

```
julia> file = jldopen("/path to my data/data.jld", "r")
ERROR: /path to my data/data.jld does not seem to be a Julia data or HDF5 file
 in jldopen at /root/.julia/v0.4/JLD/src/JLD.jl:242
 in jldopen at /root/.julia/v0.4/JLD/src/JLD.jl:253
```

what's wrong  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
close(file)
```

After writing to it.  Or, you could use the `do` block syntax as discussed in the package [documentation](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl), which is a bit safer as it will automatically close the file, even if an error occurs in writing to it or before you are able to call the `close()` function.